# Let $Q$ be a point on the circle $C$. Then the length of $PQ$ is in between the lengths of $PQ_1$ and $PQ_2$.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

Let $C$ be a circle centred at $O$ and $P$ be a point inside the circle.

The line $OP$ intersects the circle $C$ at $Q_1$ and $Q_2$.

Let $Q$ be a point on the circle $C$.

Then the length of $PQ$ is in between the lengths of $PQ_1$ and $PQ_2$.

[image]

I have observed that if $P = O$, then we have $PQ_1 = PQ_2 = PQ$.

How to prove the general case. Any hints will be useful.

---

Source: Homework Assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Q_1 = (r, 0), Q_2 = (-r, 0), Q = r (\cos \theta, \sin \theta), P = (a, 0)$ where $ 0 \le a  \le r $

$PQ_1 = r - a$

$PQ_2 = a + r$

$PQ = \sqrt{ (r \cos \theta - a)^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \theta } = \sqrt{ r^2 + a^2 - 2 a r \cos \theta } $

Since

$$ -1 \le \cos \theta \le 1 $$

then by multiplying through by $(-2 a r) $ we get

$$ -2 a r \le - 2 a r \cos \theta \le 2 a r $$

and further

$$ a^2 + r^2 - 2 a r \le a^2 + r^2  - 2 a r \cos \theta \le a^2 + r^2 + 2 a r $$

Applying the square root

$$ r - a \le PQ \le a + r $$

Thus

$$ P Q_1 \le PQ \le PQ_2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Let's extend PQ and have the intersection with the circle denoted by R. It is known that $$PQ\cdot QR=PQ_1\cdot PQ_2,$$ (similarity of triangles) so if we denote by $s=PQ+QR=PR$ and $p=PQ_1\cdot PQ_2$ we see that the segments $PQ$ and $PR$ are the solutions of the quadratic $x^2-sx+p=0$. Hence, $$PQ=(s\pm \sqrt{s^2-4p})/2$$ and these two functions of $s$ are monotone with the max/min when $s$ is the length of the diameter.